# discrete bayesian

Tags: probability, bayesian

I have an exercise where I struggle to understand a below sentence:

X (prior) is a discrete random variable that takes the value 1 with probability  $ p \in \{0,1\} $ , and the -1 value with probability 1-p.

The part which confuse mi is the  $ p \in \{0,1\} $. This is mean, 50% of the  probability the X = 1 and 50% for X = -1? So in this case: $ P_X(x=1) = p = 1/2 $?  I have just thought this because there are two elements, and the text does not give any further explanation of what is the probability of the different X values.

Or it is not sure, and we don't know the P_X(x=1)?

Regards

Comment: ok, it is turned out the other part of the exercise (which I haven't write there) text was wrongly worded. Because it looked the p need to be counted, as a number.  But obviously based on the above information it wasn't possible.  So I get stressed I misunderstand something.  It is turned out the answer just need to write in the term of the p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X is a random variable that here has two possible outcomes, 1 or -1.

p is a probability, hence can only take values in the range [0,1]

You said that P(X=1) = p, therefore as the only other possible outcome for X is -1, we must have P(X=-1) = 1-p, as the sum of the probability of all possible outcomes is 1.

Here p is unknown

Comment: so the $ p \in \{0,1\} $ just stand for: an p distribution is unknown between 0 and 1?   As the p always between 0 and 1 it looks like a unnecessary information.